# Tachanun when there is a Siyyum?

Tags: tachanun, siyum, simchah-joy-happiness

1. [Does a minyan say tachanun if there was a siyyum or if there is going to be after aleinu?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5745882#5745882) Or, is it preferable to have a Siyum on Shabbat (just for example) to avoid this *safeik*?
2. Is Tachanun recited at a Siyum of all the Masechtot of Sha"S Bavli?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siyum

Comment: There's a third option: that there is no safek and Tachanun is said.

Comment: I davened shacharit at a minyan of people going to a Siyum HaShas of Daf Yomi.  Tachanun was said at shacharit.  The mincha minyan at the siyum did not say tachanun.  Unsure if this would qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Rav Ovadia Yosef (Yabia Omer OC 4:13) discusses this topic and concludes in favor of not saying tachanun at a siyum in order to emphasize the aspect of happiness when learning Torah and thereby reward those who do learn Torah / entice others to learn Torah too.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44315/759 I suppose?

Answer (score 6):

I personally made a siyum on Shas right after mincha, and R' Herschel Schachter paskened that we shouldn't say tachanun during mincha.

Comment: Would he say the same for a siyum right after shacharis?