# Not saying Tachnun on the day of a siyum

Tags: halacha, tachanun, siyum

Is there any minhag (custom) when a person makes a siyum (finishes a mesacta or anything else that a "siyum" can be made on) that he himself doesn't say tachnun on that day?

What about in any of these situations:

He makes a siyum by night, would he not say the whole next day by shachris and mincha?

He makes a siyum after shachris but before mincha, would tachnun not be said by shachris (since this is the "day" of the siyum.) or only not by mincha.

Or perhaps any other situation.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18504/759

Comment: @DoubleAA seems more than just related! Is there any additional discussion there in the teshuva that could help answer this?

Comment: I don't recall him discussing such an opinion, but it has been some time since I last went through the responsum.

Answer (score 2):

I personally made a siyum on Shas right after mincha, and R' Herschel Schachter paskened that we shouldn't say tachanun during mincha.

Comment: This answer seems more appropriate to this question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18504/759

Comment: @DoubleAA It would have been good for my original question which was changed (by someone else) because it was seemingly a duplicate ?

Comment: In regards to the psak, sounds quite reasonable to me!

Comment: This answer has also been added there now.  Should it be deleted here or does it still apply?