# Can you make a siyum on tractate Tamid?

Tags: halacha, maseches-tamid

It's the shortest masechet and has only 7 chapters. It start from 25b, which is unusual. Can you make a siyum on it?

Comment: Why not? The fact it is printed after another tractate is just a printing convention. The fact it is short doesn't make it any less of a tractate. Here is an example of a siyum on it https://www.facebook.com/watch/live/?ref=watch_permalink&v=597031764228148

Comment: I learned Tamid in a class this year. We were close to finishing, and there was a plan to make a siyum.

Comment: You should make regular siyyumim on it (tomid).

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Too true, well said. May we merit that.

Comment: @mbloch The fact that it's short could make it less of a significant accomplishment. After all, a siyum is just a celebration of a significant accomplishment in Torah study. Any list of "what you can make a siyum on" is just one rabbi's perspective on what's significant to them.

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Would you also say that when it's easier for you to learn than for somebody else, it's less of an accomplishment?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Sure, and so would Ben Hei Hei.

Answer (score 5):

R' Ben Zion Abba Shaul writes in his responsa (Or Tzion [12:2](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_19980_134.pdf)) that one may make a *siyum* on Meseches Tamid, and this *siyum* is valid in reference to *taanis bechorim* on Erev Pesach. He also rules so regarding eating meat after Rosh Chodesh Av.

R' Mutzafi [rules](https://www.doresh-tzion.co.il/QAShowAnswer.aspx?qaid=100181) that it is not enough of a siyum to negate saying *tachanun*.

*Itim Lebinah* quotes a dispute between R' Chaim Kanievsky shlit"a and R' Elyashiv zt"l whether it is considered a siyum regarding *taanis bechorim* - R' Chaim Kanievsky rules that it isn't, whereas R' Elyashiv ruled that it is considered a *siyum*.

Comment: Some hold nowadays on any siyum we dont stop saying tachanun. That seems to be the prevalent minhag.

Comment: @Shlomy https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18504/759

Answer (score 0):

One concern is that it seems to be incomplete -- but it has been for as long as anyone has commented and other massechtot have textual issues also. It's also genuinely difficult to learn in the traditional way, because there are very few perushim and no traditional ones. But the rules for siyumim are not very firm; it's more of a pastoral issue than anything else.